# Macro issue for timing

Tags: c, macros

I am searching a nice way to create a "no action" timing (CPU useless operation for timing).

To explain my issue here is the code that I want to change to a macro :

```
int main (void)
{
  int i=0; 

  printf("Start\r\n");
  for(i=0;i<1000;i++); //LINE TO CHANGE TO A MACRO
  printf("Delayed trace\r\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: I presume it is `int main(void)` and not `maint`?4

Comment: `#define DELAY {int i; for(i=0;i<1000;i++);}`

Comment: The problem with using a for loop to "sleep" is some compilers may completely optimize it away.  Perhaps a macro that calls pthread's sleep() function would interest you?

Comment: @Josh I tried it with my compiler and it works, so I am gonna stay that way.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I would like to write like : DELAY(); int my code. Do you think :     #define DELAY() {int i; for(i=0;i<1000;i++);} would work ?

Comment: @Joze DELAY(); is work. but `if(condition) DELAY(); else doany();` this can't compile.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, `do { ... } while (0)` is the idiom.

Comment: @Shahbaz Well, I recall seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General way for defining such a macro would be:

```
#define DELAY(amount)       \
do {                        \
    /* method of delay */   \
} while (0)
```

In your case:

```
#define DELAY(amount)             \
do {                              \
    int i;                        \
    for (i = 0; i < amount; ++i); \
} while (0)
```

Comment: @ganesh, I was actually surprised there were already two answers and none referred to this. This is pretty much the only way you could write a macro that wouldn't get you in trouble

Comment: @Shahbaz.. Sometimes we try to be exotic and miss the obvious :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to introduce a delay in terms of some loop iterations, you could employ

```
#define INTRODUCE_DELAY(count) for(int i = 0; i < count; i++);
```

You could modify this through a compiler switch to invoke a `sleep` of similar `us` as shown below. In case you can't declare `i` in the `for` loop then, we can define a small function (which could potentially be `inline` as shown below

```
#ifdef WIN32
void mysleep(int count)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++);
}
#define INTRODUCE_DELAY(count) mysleep(count);
#else
#define INTRODUCE_DELAY(count) sleep(count);
#endif
```

Comment: I can't declare i in for loop with my compiler.

Comment: @Joze Please find my updated answer which should cater to your constraint.

Comment: Yep that should work. (I was at first searching a solution with no function). But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need sleep function, (Work only on unix/linux though)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#define DELAY(SEC) sleep(SEC)
```

There must be a similar function in windows.

Comment: I want really short timing for my application and the smallest timing fiction I have available is 1ms (not short enough).